# Show hidden elements of a list in a dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like to show all hidden elements of a list in a dropdown. 
This should be dynamically, based on how many options can fit in the window.

How could this be done,
or does anyone know a plugin for this?

[image]

```css
.navigation--list{
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navigation--list li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

#more{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation--list">
  <li>option 1</li>
  <li>option 2</li>
  <li>option 3</li>
  <li>option 4</li>
  <li>option 5</li>
  <li>option 6</li>
  <li>option 7</li>
  <li>option 8</li>
  <li>option 9</li>
  <li id="more">show more</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean you want this to happen dynamically based on how many options can fit in the window? Or will you statically define which options should be hidden and exist on the drop-down?

Comment: It should be dynamically, based on how many options can fit in the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding more button for list in responsive navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449543/adding-more-button-for-list-in-responsive-navigation)

Comment: Thanks @showdev. I wasnt sure what to do with that.

Comment: @JamesManges Great find. It doesn't handle the drop-down functionality, so I'm not sure it's sufficient as a duplicate -- but looks like a good start for a responsive horizontal menu.

Comment: @showdev: yeah he would need to use in conjunction with show hide. I'll add that to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this other question:

[adding more button for list in responsive navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449543/adding-more-button-for-list-in-responsive-navigation)

You will need to use some Javascript for this. You will also need to pair this with show hide.

Here is an example:

```js
var elemWidth, fitCount, fixedWidth = 120,
  $menu = $("ul#menu"),
  $collectedSet;

collect();
$(window).resize(collect);


function collect() {
  elemWidth = $menu.width();
  fitCount = Math.floor(elemWidth / fixedWidth) - 1;
  $collectedSet = $menu.children(":gt(" + fitCount + ")");
  $("#submenu").empty().append($collectedSet.clone());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submenu").hide();
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $("#submenu").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: visible;
}

ul#menu,
ol {
  height: 32px;
  max-width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul#menu > li,
ol > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 32px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

ol {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

ol > li {
  min-width: 120px;
}

ol ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  right: 10%;
}

ol li ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>Option One</li>
    <li>Option Two</li>
    <li>Option Three</li>
    <li>Option Four</li>
    <li>Option Five</li>
    <li>Option Six</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li class="show">
      Show more
      <ul id="submenu"></ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```